# Inserting more than one variable to linked list

Tags: c

I have a linked list like this. I have to populate it from a text file. And I am using a function like below to read from text file and populate the list. But the program stops working when I compile it. No errors on Build Messages. I tried to all variables one by one and only int id works without a problem.

```
struct node
{
    int id;
    char name[25];
    int posts;
    int following;
    int followers;
    char date[20];
    char time [20];
    struct node* next;
};
    
    int tmp_id, tmp_posts, tmp_following, tmp_followers;
    char tmp_name[25], tmp_date[20], tmp_time[20];
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    struct node *tmp, *head, *last, *first;
    head=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    head->next = NULL;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%d;%s %s\n", &tmp_id, tmp_name, &tmp_posts, &tmp_following, &tmp_followers, tmp_date, tmp_time) != EOF)
    {
        
        tmp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
        tmp->id=tmp_id;
        strcpy(tmp->name, tmp_name);
        tmp->posts=tmp_posts;
        tmp->following=tmp_following;
        tmp->followers=tmp_followers;
        strcpy(tmp->date, tmp_date);
        strcpy(tmp->time, tmp_time);
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if(head->next==NULL)
        {
            head->next = tmp;
            first = last = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = tmp;
            last = tmp;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
```

Comment: `sizeof(struct node *)` should be `sizeof(struct node)`. You're only allocated 4 or 8 bytes, which is much smaller than the structure, so you're causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Remember this general rule: When you call `malloc()` the type in `sizeof()` should have one less `*` than the pointer type you're assigning to. Or just use `sizeof(*ptrvariable)` where `ptrvariable` is the variable you're assigning from `malloc()`.

Comment: I don't see where the tmp variable is declared? tmp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));

Comment: @Barmar That "*" saved me. Also thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Kozmotronik It's declared here: `struct node *tmp, *head, *last, *first;`

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp = fopen(filename, "r");`  There many ways the function: `fopen()` can fail.  So, immediately following this statement should be:  `if( ! fp ) { perror( "fopen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  This will output to `stderr` both you error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `tmp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen failed" )`  probably followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `while(fscanf(fp, "%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%d;%s %s\n", &tmp_id, tmp_name, &tmp_posts, &tmp_following, &tmp_followers, tmp_date, tmp_time) != EOF)`  1) best to check for a positive indication rather than EOF.  In this scenario, check for 7.  2) when using a character set, like: `%[...]` or the input format conversion specifier: `%s`, always include a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length on the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoid any buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: Please post a couple of lines from the input file, so we help with any formatting errors

Comment: OT: the posted contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E.  20, 25  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or an `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the posted code is missing any (and all) function definitions.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: *I tried to all variables one by one and only int id works without a problem.*  please post the problems you have encountered.

Comment: regarding: *But the program stops working when I compile it.*  what do you mean by this statement?

Comment: regarding; `head=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    head->next = NULL;`  This results in the first entry in the linked list never being used.  Suggest: `struct node *head = NULL;` then when checking for an empty list use `if ( head == NULL )` rather than `if ( head->next == NULL )`

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for all the comments but Barmar's suggestion solved the problem. What I meant is if compile and run the code builder doesn't gives any error messages. But the .exe stops working. after assigning the data from text to struct. When I tried to print the elements of struct to test if the problem was with fscanf or assigning , only int id was printing. But the problem was solved by Bramar's suggestion..

Comment: Bramar gave you what was wrong with the program.  I gave you what needed to be done to result in robust code.